# Proving a certain graph has two disjoint trails that partition the Edges set.

Tags: graph-theory

> Let G be a simple, connected graph with no loops. 
>   Prove that if G has exactly 4 vertices with odd degree, then there exists two disjoint trails, $T_1,T_2$ such that $E_{T_1}\cap E_{T_2}=\emptyset$ and $E_{T_1}\cup E_{T_2}=E_G$.

I was trying to use the theorem that says that every graph with exactly two odd degree vertices has a trail connecting them, but couldn't get far. Could you guys give me some tips?

Answer (score 1):

Let $a,b,c,d$ be the vertices of odd degree. Add edges $ab$ and $cd$ (this may create multiple edges, but these do not hurt us).

The resulting (multi-)graph is even, so it has an Eulerian circuit. Removing edges $ab$ and $cd$ from this circuit produces the desired partition.